# flink sliding window will consider duplicate message?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

suppose I am using event time processing and in sliding windows time window 10 and sliding factor 5 seconds.

so now for example some message arrive at 8 seconds event time so it will fall in first

```
 window-1  1 to 10.
```

now it slides 5 seconds and now that window is 5 to 15. so the same messsage which window1 have consider , window2 will also consider that message.

```
  window2- 5 to 15
```

so my question is that not duplicate message it will affect my calcualtion ?
suggest me I am thinking ok or not?
and if it consider bothe messages then how to consider it as unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A record is added to all sliding windows that overlap with its timestamp, e.g., in your example, the record at time `8` will be added to both windows `1 to 10` and `5 to 15`.